# how to store and get stored data in to a session in c# if it stored using var

Tags: c#, class, session, var, class-library

I'm getting data from web service like follow

```
 string serviceUrl = "https://www.mscholid.com/assings/handlqueryrs/myprod.ashx";
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl);
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();


            var rootResult = XElement.Parse(result);
```

now I want to put this root result into a session

Session["rootv"] = rootResult;

then I want to retrieve it.
**store function should do inside a class**

```
  public class NileResult
    {


        public dynamic nilecruiseFinalData_Images(string selectedID)
        {
            string serviceUrl = "https://www.mscholid.com/assings/handlqueryrs/myprod.ashx";
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl);
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();


            var rootResult = XElement.Parse(result);
//in here  I want to store in to a session
 }
}
```

how can I do this.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Session["rootv"] = rootResult; will work for you.

Comment: @Dr.Stitch you know this is the answer. Why not put 2 mins to convert it to Answer and close the matter.

Comment: @nikhilvartak, i always waiting for a response before i put my answer.

Comment: @Dr.Stitch Agreed and I respect that. But isn't it too obvious in this case! OP just needed a way to reference `Session` object in a class that does not inherit from `Page` class.

Comment: @nikhilvartak, agreed. i just want to have a rule in answering question but for you i will post the asnwer.

Comment: "HttpContext" not exists in the current context

Comment: you must have using System.Web;

Comment: I have already import it.but it gives this error.I'm using this inside a class library

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the session of the request, you can use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["rootv"] = rootResult;
```

HttpContext.Current is the current context of the request.

Comment: done, thanx. but how can I retrieve it in another place to put the data in to a list. I upvoted.

Comment: it defends, if you're using web application you can access it by var result = Session["rootv"]; or if you're in another class library you can var result = HttpContext.Current.Session["rootv"];

Comment: but when I use like this, I cant query or cannot use foreach with this `result`.why is that

Comment: You need to cast it to your expected object, example XElement result = (XElement)HttpContext.Current.Session["rootv"];